# File transaction handling in multiple image upload in codeigniter

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, transactions

I am doing multiple image upload in CodeIgniter and I want to create a file transaction handling system to upload images.
The problem is when we select any nonimage file between the images then CodeIgniter can not have any system to rollback to remove the uploaded images.
what should I do to manage this image upload?

the same problem occurs when any bigger size image uploaded between the allowed size images. CI upload some files and when the bigger image comes then CI gives an error but till the previous images will get uploaded.

The final goal is that if any error occurs between file upload then all the process will get rollback.

So how can I manage this file transaction like we handle the transaction in the MySQL

Comment: I think there is no default answer. I think you can use the system schedulers such as crontab in linux.

Comment: @Star_Man sir, i don't know much about system schedulers. So can you tell me any best practices to this? or other "ways" to solve this issue.

Comment: In linux system, I recommend     "crontab", and in windows system, you can use default scheduler - "Task Schedular"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your image upload function capable enough to handle it. Try something like this:

```
$fileNames = array();
// To hold the the file names of all the files available in $_FILES

$fileStatus = array();
// hold  the file name wise status i.e. TRUE/FALSE like filename => status

// Put a check to ensure all files have a TRUE status, if any one fails then unlink (delete) all the uploaded file for the current session
```

Comment: sir, ok I get the file name of all uploaded element.  Can you send me any reference link on this?

Comment: Bro this is just an idea so you have to create login on your own

Comment: Ok Ok sir, I am trying right now with creating a temp. folder to upload images in it and if all goes ok then i move it to the original directory. thanks for the advice sir. @Mayank Pandeyz